# How does the premiums for private insurance in Germany rise over time?

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I came to Germany more than a year ago and in the beginning i was tricked into getting into private insurance when i did not have much idea ([Is there any way i can move from private health insurance to public one without lowering my income?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/is-there-any-way-i-can-move-from-private-health-insurance-to-public-one-without)). After trying everything i can, i think i can safely say i am stuck with private insurance now.

After this acceptance, i am now gather info on how is it going to be several years down the line. I am now 30 and planning to stay in Germany forever. So far i am getting conflicting information on how is it going to be with the premiums later in life. I read articles and hear from some people that the private insurance premiums can go as high as 1000 Euros per month at the time of retirement. Some says it remains somewhere around the public insurance premiums. I really have no idea which one to believe. I would rather find a nice job in another country while the market is still hot than being stranded in a foreign land in old age.

My questions:
- I have Gothaer private insurance and they charge about 550 per month. Any idea how much is the premium going to be when i am around the age of 60 ?
- I am paying less than the public insurance at the moment. Would i be fine if i think i can just save the money saved now to pay for increased premiums later ?

Comment: Private insurance is a contract between you and the insurance company. What does the policy itself say about future premiums and how they might change?

Comment: I will try to ask some friend who can read in German to go through the contract. But if i believe the agents, it's not clearly mentioned in the contract as there are several factors that can affect the premium and they assure me that it will not "go out of hands" per say.